# How do I pass JSON data retrieved with SocketIO to my Routes in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-router, flask-socketio

I need to get the variables in my routes to update from the JSON data and also sometimes emit data, but I haven't figured out how to pass `response` to my Routes for accessing.

App.js file where the JSON is retrieved:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import validate from 'validate.js';

import theme from './theme';
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
import './assets/scss/index.scss';
import validators from './common/validators';
import Routes from './Routes';

import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

validate.validators = {
  ...validate.validators,
  ...validators
};

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.emit('test', {"name": "jim"})
    socket.on("test_client", data => {
      setResponse(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Routes.js where the Routes are created:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import { RouteWithLayout } from './components';
import { Main as MainLayout, Minimal as MinimalLayout } from './layouts';

import {
  Login as LoginView,
  Dashboard as DashboardView,
  Trading as TradingView,
  OrderHistory as OrderHistoryView,
  Account as AccountView,
  Settings as SettingsView,
  NotFound as NotFoundView
} from './views';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Redirect
        exact
        from="/"
        to="/dashboard"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={LoginView}
        exact
        layout={MinimalLayout}
        path="/login"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={DashboardView}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path="/dashboard"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={TradingView}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path="/trading"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={OrderHistoryView}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path="/orderhistory"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={AccountView}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path="/account"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={SettingsView}
        exact
        layout={MainLayout}
        path="/settings"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <RouteWithLayout
        component={NotFoundView}
        exact
        layout={MinimalLayout}
        path="/not-found"
        data={props.response}
      />
      <Redirect to="/not-found" />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

1. I get the JSON data from my Flask backend using SocketIO
2. JSON data is saved in response (I believe)
3. I then want the JSON data to be accessible by each Route in Routes (the pages).

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: pass it via props

Comment: something like <Router history={browserHistory} data={response}> ?

Comment: That passes it to Router, not to your routes.. pass it to your actual Routes. or if you want something quazi global you can use context

Comment: so just <Routes data={response}> , and then in my routes I can just use {props.response.name} for example?

Comment: props aren't magic. you pass them and access them just like passing arguments from one function to another

Comment: and your example it wouldn't be `props.response` it would be `props.data` since that's what you named the prop

Comment: not sure why the concept of props confuses me so much when it comes to routes, going to try this, thank you

Comment: maybe if you add your Routes component to the question it would be easier to write an answer

Comment: I was adding it as you were probably typing that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass props along:

App.js:

```
<Routes data={response} />
```

Routes.js:

```
const Routes = ({ data }) =>
  ...
  <RouteWithLayout
    // pass props here
    component={routeProps => <LoginView {...routeProps} data={data} />}
    exact
    layout={MinimalLayout}
    path="/login"
  />
  ...
}
```

Comment: I added this to each Route, but since I have components inside the Routes, for example `Dashboard` has a `TotalProfit` component it displays that I need the JSON to be inside of, Would I pass this prop into the `TotalProfit` component as well?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. if you need that information in `TotalProfits` how could it get there if you don't pass props?

Comment: It's just like a function... how can a function access something if it's not enclosed or you didn't pass an argument

Comment: I guess I keep assuming the props automatically pass from the parent component displaying the child component to the child